# Event for before invoice creation magento 2

Tags: admin, orders, event-observer, invoice, create-invoice

Do we have any event for invoice before create?

When we click on invoice and about to submit the form , do we have any event there?

Want to do some modification before creating invoice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sales_order_invoice_register` that is right after the invoice has been created and before the first save in the database.

This event is also triggered if invoices are created automatically.

Comment: No I want before creating invoice, I already tried this on but it fired after my need

Comment: Than you should use a plugin. For example before `toInvoice` in `Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\Order` that's the method where the invoice is created.

Comment: Hi @HelgeB Do you which event we use before cancelling the order in admin.
Same like invoice

Comment: I tried (\Magento\Sales\Model\Order cancel method for plugin but that helped me

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve? I think that should be the focus of another question, please write a question with a little details and I will have a look at that. If we are done with this question,please accept the answer.

Comment: before cancelling order I want to modify that same as invoice,

Comment: That should be possible with a plugin before cancel but if it doesn't work we should look at your code what exactly doesn't work